# Is "Emperor of Mexico" the same as "Mexican Emperor"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Are "Emperor of Mexico" and "Mexican Emperor" true synonyms or is there a bit of a semantic difference?

For example, "Mexican Emperor" could be considered any Emperor, regardless of the country they rule, who happens to be of Mexican heritage, whereas "Emperor of Mexico" can really only be interpreted one way.

Comment: It is probably dependent on the article you use...i.e. definite, or indefinite.

Comment: Synonyms of what? "Emperor of Mexico" is an actual title. "Mexican Emperor" seems more generic. https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Emperor+of+Mexico&t=ffab&ia=web

Comment: The Mexican Emperor of China was deposed following a bloody civil war.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Also George I was the first German king of England.

Comment: *Emperor of Mexico* has a slightly farcical tone, probably due to this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximilian_I_of_Mexico

Answer (score 1):

Without any other context, "Mexican Emperor" would normally be interpreted as "Emperor of Mexico". But it can be used in other contexts, like "Mexican Emperor of America", which would then mean the Emperor of America who is Mexican. Or in answer to the question "Which Emperor of China are you referring to?", the answer could be "The Mexican Emperor".

This is a common ambiguity when using a nationality as an adjective modifying a role. It can be used to qualify the role itself, or to qualify a person fitting the role.

Answer (score 0):

They are both fine for use, but I think you've answered your own question. The Emperor of Mexico *does* sounds a *little* more specifically related to the context in which you're meaning.